# Rename certain characters from filenames in all files in a folder and his sub-folders

Tags: windows, powershell, replace, directory

I Want to replace certain character from my files
for example

i want to change > "original" -> "something else"

i use this script to replace it in one folder only using powershell

```
Dir |>> Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "original","something " }
```

the issue is , with that code , that's only replace the files inside one folder and it don't replace them in the subfolders
i need it to replace it in file on the folder and in the sub folder files too , is that possible?

( **i'm kinda new to this** )

note : this code shows this error when there's any subfolders with the files

erorr =

```
Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:2 char:1
+ Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "original","something " }
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (F:\folder-name\...ff\py-compat:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

**Operating system : windows**

info

**Operating system model : windows 10**

Comment: 2nd line of the paragraph : quick fix > i want to change > "original" -> "something"

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'TheRootFolder' -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace 'original', 'something')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of directories the `rename-item` commandlet gets the same path as input and as value of the `-newname` parameter, so it errors out.
Adding the `-verbose` and `-whatif` switch parameters to the command will show that.

Use the `-Path` parameter to specify the base path you want to recurse, the `-recurse` switch parameter to recursively visit each subfolder, the `-file` switch parameter  to filter out directories, and/or use the `-filter` parameter to include a subset of files.

Example:

```
get-childitem -Recurse -File -Path 'c:\temp' | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "original","replacement }
```